# android change datetime format

Tags: java, android, datetime-format

I have date-time in format `05.12.2014 16:43:43` and I am trying to change its format to this `MM/dd/yyyy`. This is my source:

```
String mydate = "05.12.2014 16:43:43";
SimpleDateFormat srcDf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss");

try {
    Date date = srcDf.parse(mydate);
    SimpleDateFormat destDf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    mydate = destDf.format(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have an error in first SimpleDateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat srcDf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss");
```

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to

```
SimpleDateFormat srcDf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

So that is match your String.

The symbols are explained here
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

> Letter    Date or Time Component  Presentation    ExamplesG   Era designator  Text    AD
>
> y     Year    Year    1996; 96
>
> Y     Week year   Year    2009; 09
>
> M     Month in year   Month   July; Jul; 07
>
> w     Week in year    Number  27
>
> W     Week in month   Number  2
>
> D     Day in year     Number  189
>
> d     Day in month    Number  10
>
> F     Day of week in month    Number  2
>
> E     Day name in week    Text    Tuesday; Tue
>
> u     Day number of week (1 = Monday, ..., 7 = Sunday)    Number  1
>
> a     Am/pm marker    Text    PM
>
> H     Hour in day (0-23)  Number  0
>
> k     Hour in day (1-24)  Number  24
>
> K     Hour in am/pm (0-11)    Number  0
>
> h     Hour in am/pm (1-12)    Number  12
>
> m     Minute in hour  Number  30
>
> s     Second in minute    Number  55
>
> S     Millisecond     Number  978
>
> z     Time zone   General time zone   Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00
>
> Z     Time zone   RFC 822 time zone   -0800
>
> X     Time zone   ISO 8601 time zone  -08; -0800; -08:00